# Sendkeys("{BACKSPACE}") inserts "B" characters instead of backspacing

Tags: silverlight, automated-tests, sendkeys, coded-ui-tests

I have a TextBox declared in a Silverlight project with contents “123456” and then use the following code in a Coded UI test.  First it searches and clicks the TextBox to set focus, and then tries to delete characters.

```
currencyPage.ClickEditByAutomationId("textBox");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{END}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACKSPACE}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACKSPACE}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACKSPACE}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACKSPACE}");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACKSPACE}");
```

This is the resulting text in my TextBox: 123456BBBBB

What am I doing wrong?  XAML of the textbox:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Keyboard.SendKeys("{BACK}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Keyboard.SendKeys(@"{BACKSPACE}");` or `Keyboard.SendKeys("{{BACKSPACE}}");`

Comment: Your first solution still appends B characters, and the second solution appends {} over and over.